# How do I use variables from this constructor in other methods in Java?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, constructor

So I have a constructor that looks like this

```
public Maze(String[] textmaze, int startRow, int startCol, int finishRow, int finishCol){
```

I want to access the variables startRow, startCol, finishRow, and finishCol however those variables can only be passed in as parameters from another class(which I can't modify). So how would I use those variables from the constructor in another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
class Maze{
    private int startRow, startCol, finishRow, finishCol;

    public Maze(String[] textmaze, int startRow, int startCol, int finishRow, int finishCol){
        this.startRow = startRow;
        this.startCol = startCol;
        this.finishRow = finishRow;
        this.finishCol = finishCol;
    }

    private void someMethod(){
        System.out.println(startRow);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save them to properties or fields. Here's the documentation about [properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).